# How do I find out where a script is attached to in Unity?

Tags: unity

*I'm using Unity 2017.03.0f3 and I have a scripts folder with scripts (C#).*

Suppose I forget, or am working on someone else's project:

How do I know exactly which scripts are attached to what GameObjects or PreFabs, without clicking and going through all the Hierarchy objects please, and by first clicking on a script in the Project view?

I hope that's specific enough.

Comment: I think the closest you can get to what you are looking for is by right clicking the script and choosing "Find References in Scene"

Answer (score 1):

The hierarchy search allows you to filter by component. You'll need to type the entire name of the component or script. It will gray out the other objects and show only the objects with that script attached in the hierarchy. More details here: http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/can-search-scene-objects-components-type/